# Wordpress served by nginx under non-root url

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, wordpress

I'm trying to move my server from apache to the Nginx starting with a blog. The blog is only a part of the website and should be available under /blog/admin (I'm using WordPress only as a backend).

In apache I was using a directory directive and alias:

```
    Alias /blog/admin /var/www/wordpress

    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
            AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

And I have no idea how to mimic this behavior under nginx. So far I've got a working wordpress with:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name my-domain.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;

        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

I've played with:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name my-domain.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;

        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location /blog/admin {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

But without success. The wordpress is still available at `my-domain.net` (and it should not) and it is not available under `my-domain.net/blog/admin`.

The only difference is that `my-domain.net/blog/admin` returns status 302 and redirects me to the root `my-domain.net/`.

How can I achieve the same behavior as with apache?

To make things clear - the directory with Wordpress installation:

> /var/www/wordpress

The URL under which the Wordpress should be available:

> domain.com/blog/admin

I've tried with an updated configuration thanks to @Paul

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # The root directive here sets the default root directory for the entire server block, unless configured otherwise in a location block
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name my-domain.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;

        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location /blog/admin/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ /blog/admin/.*\.php$ {
                root /var/www/wordpress;
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

}
```

Unfortunately, the /blog/admin/ does not lead to the wordpress installation directory

```
2022/08/18 15:27:42 [error] 70754#70754: *1 open() "/var/www/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 79.175.220.248, server: my-domain.net, request: "GET /blog/admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.net"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to ServerFault. In order to answer the question, I need clarifications: What is the exact path on the filesystem where WordPress `index.php` is located? What is the URL you want to use to access WordPress?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've extended the post.

Comment: Could you also have the "without success" statement? What was the request you made? What was the result?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've described that.

Comment: The "I've played with" section is incomplete. Please post the entire server block configuration you placed that within.

Comment: @Paul I've posted the entire server block.

Answer (score 0):

I think your output is not your desired output but sounds like the expected output.

This *might* work:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # The root directive here sets the default root directory for the entire server block, unless configured otherwise in a location block
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name my-domain.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;

        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location /blog/admin/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/admin/index.php?$args;
                root /var/www/wordpress;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                }
        }
}
```

I think with this you can at least see you set the server block `root` directory to your WordPress directory, which the expected output would be to serve the WordPress directory when your server name is requested (without a path).

If not fixed in the above configuration, I believe the 302 when serving that directory may be part of the WordPress configuration. Try using an unconfigured installation and see if that at least loads, or if you have access to the WordPress dashboard set the desired URL within WordPress.

Comment: I should also have pointed out you are serving the WordPress installation unencrypted over Internet. This is problematic on *many* levels.

Comment: Also, be sure to read [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: I was trying to use your config. The index.html available under /var/www is working fine. Unfortunately - /blog/admin is not accesible. Error log contains information: 2022/08/18 15:16:16 [error] 70709#70709: *1 open() "/var/www/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 11.111.111.111, server: my-domain.net, request: "GET /blog/admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.net"

Comment: `open() "/var/www/index.php" failed` It looks like you don't have `root /var/www/wordpress` under the `location` block. Did you catch my edit that includes this in the configuration? Also, it is easier if you update your question, even if with a second complete configuration that isn't working. Sometimes these things are hard to hash out in a comments section.

Comment: I've added this log with full configuration to the first post.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used the service this way because it's easier to just use the one `root` directive and not use different paths because complex configurations usually make things more difficult than just changing the path to the package files. It may be you need to make one `location /blog/admin/ { root /var/www/wordpress; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; location ~ \.php$ { <phpconfigs> } }`, or something.

Comment: Could you update the main answer? I'd like to be sure that I've merged this config correctly.

Comment: I've changed your location regex(to location ~ .*\.php$), and the issue is still the same - 1 open() "/var/www/index.php" failed

Comment: I hate regex because I never learned it proper and mostly cargo cult. That meta-character is not in the update I posted. Also, I updated a second time to remove the `*`.

Comment: I should also point out that there currently is no configuration to support `.php` locations outside of the `/var/www/wordpress`.

Comment: I'm aware of that. /var/www will be purely html based. The issue is still the same, no /var/www/index.php for GET /blog/admin/ HTTP/1.1

Comment: I added the path to `try_files`, which is what I did on a somewhat similar working configuration from an install archive.